# Win32: modal dialog leaves a trail in the client area of parent/owner

Tags: winapi, modal-dialog, dialog

I'm writing a plug-in for an app; the plug-in is to display a modal dialog. It displays just fine, but when I move it, it leaves a trail on the screen, i.e. the window below doesn't redraw. Some parts of it do redraw (all standard Windows controls, e.g. toolbar or scrollbar), but the rest of the client area does not.

I'm using `DialogBoxIndirectParam`; the `hWnd` is the top window of the app, the template I construct on the fly and the dialog flags are `WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | DS_MODALFRAME |  DS_SETFONT | WS_SYSMENU`, plus the function sets some flags itself, e.g. `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS`. The dialog class is standard (CS+DBLCLKS,CS_SAVEBITS) The dialog procedure is very basic, it only handles the `WM_CLOSE` message at the moment.

I tried Google but didn't manage find anything directly relevant. I tried to compare my dialog class with other dialogs of the same app and also checked the messages logs, but I didn't see any drastic differences.

Why doesn't the parent/owner redraw and how do I fix it?

**Update**. Here's the relevant calls.

Calling the dialog:

```
class Dialog(object):
    def run(self):
        t = cast(c_char_p(self.template()), LPCDLGTEMPLATE)
        p = GetActiveWindow()
        r = DialogBoxIndirectParamW(0, t, p, dialog_proc_2, py_object(self))
```

Window procedure:

```
def dialog_proc(window, message, wparam, lparam):
    if message == WM_CLOSE:
        EndDialog(window, IDCANCEL);
        return 1
    return 0
```

This is Python code :) it's embedded Python working via `ctypes`. The plug-in runs in the main thread; the host application makes a synchronous call, i.e it waits for the called function to return. `self.template()` returns `DLGTEMPLATEEX` data I prepare on the fly; I believe I do this correctly, because the dialog displays and when I check it with Spy all flags seems to be set (except that there's a few more). I don't use the instance handle, because I don't load anything from resources. I believe I correctly wrapped all functions and constants, but I can post the definitions too. `GetActiveWindow` (or `GetForegroundWindow`) returns the pointer to the app's main window; it's a MDI app and it repaints everything except the client area of a MDI window:

[image: Screenshot of the problem showing the trail]

Here I moved the window over all the visible windows (toolbars, buttons, etc.) and the only part that doesn't repaint is the client area of the MDI doc.

Comment: Post a small repro project that exhibits this behavior to a file sharing service.

Comment: Your parents WM_PAINT or WM_ERASEBKGND handling is likely incorrect. Show us the code.

Comment: I'm not sure I can prepare a working snippet; it's a DLL that embeds Python, the code is in Python too and the WinAPI functions are called via ctypes :) The big idea is to have a scripted dialog constructor. But I can post all the API calls here, of course. I also don't have access to parent code; as I said, it's a plug-in. I have access to code of another plug-in that also shows a dialog, but it seems to be same, except that it restores parent's focus when closing the dialog.

Comment: It's the parent code that will most likely be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the message queue to be pumped to make the paint cycle works. It seems that there is some pumping occurring (you say that some controls re-draw).

Since modal dialogs run their own message pump, I'm going to take a wild guess that the host for your plugin has some special treatment of messages, quite possibly erroneous, in its message pump and that your standard dialog box message pump does things differently.

I'm guessing and making large leaps of faith, but I suspect your host app's message loop isn't of the standard `TranslateMessage` / `DispatchMessage` form. If so then you are truly hosed.

Without more details it's really impossible to say anything with much certainty. As Hans says, a minimal reproduction would make the problem easy to solve.

Comment: I just tried to use `NULL` as `hWndParent` and, unfortunately, it didn't make any difference.

Comment: If you host app is FileMaker I think you are in big trouble. That is one of the worst programs in the history of computers. I have no confidence in their ability to write a proper message loop.

Comment: Just do a web search for *filemake plugin redraw* and you will other  people with the same problem as you. I have reached my verdict, FileMaker is guilty!

Comment: Yep, true, there's a guy with exactly the same problem (http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-444131.html). And he didn't seem to have it fixed :) But some plug-ins do display dialogs somehow, so, I figure, I have to ask those guys how they manage to do this.

Comment: @David, do you think it's possible to have an workaround and if so, what could it be? I'm going to try making direct calls to the main window's window procedure, but I don't know enough to decide if this is the best way.

Comment: @Mikhail You can't call the main window's window procedure. It has to paint its own windows, you can't do it. I'd contact the FileMaker people and send them your trivial plugin that manifests this fault.

Comment: @David, I'm not sure, but could this be the cause: FM apparently uses MFC and MFC main loop is slightly different: it calls PumpMessage which then calls (virtual and, apparently, overidden) methods in application and/or window classes. When a modal dialog box is on, PumpMessage isn't called. Here's MS info about this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126874. I still have no idea how to use this info, but at least I feel I'm on a right track.

Comment: @Mikhail That looks interesting but I'd be surprised if that explained it all. MFC apps and standard dialog manager modal dialogs do play nice together. Here's another idea. What if FileMaker runs its plugins out of a separate thread, perhaps to have some isolation. If the main thread code waited on the plugin thread then you could see this behaviour. You would see it if FileMaker used WaitForSingleObject. If instead it used one of the MsgWaitFor*** wait functions then it could keep its UI alive. Could you check, perhaps using Spy++ whether the plugin runs in a different thread?

Comment: @Mikhail Also, what version of FileMaker? Have you contacted the FileMaker support? I'm sure they'd be able to help.

Comment: @David Yes, the plug-in runs in the same thread. I've written to FM support and to some other developers, but haven't got an answer yet, except a hint from one of plug-in makers about 'hooking into FileMaker message loop', which I cannot quite place into my mental model of Win32 API. (They mentioned paid support, so I'm somewhat reluctant to ask for clarification.) :)

Comment: @Mikhail Same thread is good news, I suppose. Good luck with this. It would be pretty rum if they charged you for a problem like this which is clearly of their own making! It wouldn't happen if to you if you were my customer!

Comment: @David What puzzles me is that there's quite a few FM plug-ins that display modal dialogs and these plug-ins run just fine. The link I posted a few comments above actually mentions an older version of FM and I found some other evidence that newer versions should not have this problem. This kind of hardens my MFC suspicion; maybe with MFC the issue simply doesn't exist.

Comment: @David No, the paid support idea didn't came from FMI; these were guys who sell some dialog plug-in. And I'm not even their customer, so I guess this is fair.

Comment: @Mikhail Are you on an old version of FM?

Comment: @David No, I'm using a newer version: v10, while the link talks about v5 or 6. There was a large change in v7. I'm going to post another question about MFC host/Win32 DLL relationship.

Comment: @David Well, I think MFC is the cause: it turned out that MFC modal dialogs are not really modal (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/notmodaldialogs.aspx?msg=3289022), so my naive DialogBox() certainly disrupted their clever message handling :)

Comment: @Mikhail Are you sure that hasn't been changed in a more recent MFC? I know they've done a lot of work on it. It would be hard to believe that it was still so broken! Perhaps FM is using the decrepit MFC associated with MSVC6.  Anyway, this does seem promising.