# MFC application and a non-MFC modal dialog

Tags: winapi, mfc, modal-dialog

I'm writing a Win32 plug-in DLL for a third-party MFC app. The DLL needs to display a modal dialog. When I do this using `DialogBox()` or other plain Win32 API (e.g. I tried to write my own modal loop), the main application's window doesn't redraw all elements: it redraws standard elements, but not the client area. Modeless dialogs display just fine.

[image: Screenshot]

I suspect this happens because MFC doesn't really have modal dialogs in Win32 sense. It can only have one message loop and a separate loop in `DialogBox()` disrupts its delicate machinery. Here's [a CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/notmodaldialogs.aspx?msg=3289022) that explains this. But this CodeProject article is 9 years old, so maybe things have changed since then. Could somebody shed some light on this? The app uses MFC 8 (i.e. `mfc80.dll`).

**Update**. Here's a link to the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058929/win32-modal-dialog-leaves-a-trail-in-the-client-area-of-parent-owner); it may contain some additional information.

**Update 2**. Thanks everyone; I really appreciate all the advice, it certainly helps me to get the big picture of how things fit together. The first path I'm going to explore is to use native MFC 'modal' dialogs. (Since I do all this from Python, I'll use Python bindings for MFC, `pywin32`). This will take some time; when it's ready, I'll update the post with results.

Comment: +1 good question, I'll be interested to see the answer!

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058929 of which this question is a followup (more or less).

Comment: could you please use Spy++ (comes with Visual Studio) or some other similar application (one I know can be found at http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy) to find out whether the client area of the "Console" window is more than a single child window?!

Comment: @STATUS There are a few child windows: at the top is a thick XTPTooBbar, below is a Dialog (#32770) (the one with 'Layout'), then there's also two scrollbars and a custom 'grow box' between them (not visible here). They all redraw properly. There's no other child windows. What does not redraw is the client area of the 'Console' window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every thread can have a message loop. Put your modal dialog into a separate thread and emulate the standard behavior of Windows by disabling the parent  window.

*Edit:* after some discussion (see below) it appears that the parent code behaves incorrectly.

Still, I think there are possible workarounds. One could be a parent window (to the modal dialog, but child to the one that currently behaves incorrectly) that overlays the erroneous window content, but redraws it from a DC in memory to mimic correct behavior. Of course the parent window still would have to be disabled. Another solution may be to subclass the parent window, to correct the behavior. Since the plugin would run within the same process, the implementation should be straightforward.

Comment: That's unlikely to work because this plugin is called by the host app synchronously.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Right, based on what part of the original question? Besides, it _does not matter_ whether the host app calls it synchronously, because the plugin could be written to block in its call (as the host app expects) until the thread that contains the message loop (and does all the dialog work) exits.

Comment: @STATUS based on the fact that it must be blocking in the main loop for the main app to be failing to redraw.

Comment: @David Heffernan: So what you say is actually that the application simply does not behave properly (or, to put it differently: does not support real "modal plugins"). Because a call to `DialogBox()` _does_ in fact disable the parent (as I wrote) and a disabled parent needs no redrawing (and whatever is needed is being done by Windows). Besides, emulating this behavior with an extra thread is still possible by having a "proper" window display the saved canvas of the client area of the parent. In any other case RCE is always an option, to turn the right levers inside the application itself.

Comment: @STATUS I believe that OP has tried with parent = NULL. Take a look at his previous question.

Comment: @STATUS: So this is a kind of a confirmation that there's no other way round :) Sorry I didn't mention that the host makes a synchronous call, but I don't quite understand why “it does not matter” — I cannot return from the call, so the main loop won't have a chance to execute.

Comment: @David Heffernan: wasn't aware of that question (assuming you mean question 5058929). Parent == NULL would be wrong, though - for several reasons. If the host application is implemented properly, the parent should be the main window of the host application and `WM_ERASEBKGND` and friends will do the rest. Thanks for the reference, gives some insight into the details that are missing from this question.

Comment: @STATUS Sorry I misunderstood your comment concerning disabling the parent. That should not stop it repainting! I agree that Q would be much improved with reference to previous question and of course since I knew of that previous question, I was probably too quick to judge your answer not realising that you didn't have that background. Am happy to rescind the down-vote!

Comment: @STATUS I tried this with parent set to the main window (this is what GetActive/ForegroundWindow returns anyway). I also tried to explicitly repaint it with RedrawWindow with all the proper flags (invalidate, updatenow, allchidlren, and even internalpaint), it flickered like hell, but didn't repaint the client area :)

Comment: @Mikhail @STATUS I think the idea would be that you would take a copy of the FileMaker window and then redraw that on FileMaker's behalf.

Comment: @Mikhail Edoshin: it's the gray area we're talking about, right? Is that a single child window or are those actual skinned Windows controls? Could you check?

Comment: @David Heffernan: yes, that would be option one from the two workarounds suggested in my edited answer. Subclassing would probably be a bit messier, specifically since this is done in Python.

Comment: @STATUS I'm not sure I'd be brave enough to attempt to subclass an MFC window!!

Comment: @STATUS @David There is a special brew of MFC wrapped for Python: Pythonwin or pywin32 (the name is somewhat misleading). See, for example, http://onlamp.com/pub/a/python/excerpts/chpt20/pythonwin.html I think I'll try it first, except that it will take some time, because I'll have to recompile it. Will report as soon as I'm ready.